# google chart: vAxis max value

Tags: charts

I want to set a maximum value for the Y-axis (vertical). Unfortunately, it increases immediately when a larger value comes. What am I doing wrong?

(in Tasmota)

```
; 4h power chart - new value every 30s
$<div id="chart1" style="text-align:center;width:400px"></div>
$gc(lt s4h "wr" "Leistung [W]" cstr2)
$var options = {
$chartArea:{left:60,width:'83%%'},
$legend:'none',
**$vAxis:{format:'# W',minValue:0,maxValue:300},**
$explorer:{actions:['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']},
$series: {0: {type: 'area'}},              
$title:'Verbrauch 4 Stunden [Watt]'
$};
$gc(e)
```

maxValue 300
I google an ask stuff. Nobody knows the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try setting [`viewWindow.max`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547082/google-visualization-vaxis-maxvalue-property-not-working)

```
$vAxis:{format:'# W',minValue:0,maxValue:300, viewWindow: {max: 300, min: 0}},
```

Comment: THANKS! IT WORKS! 

sorry for asking on a beginner basis: how can I also add the min? Unfortunately my attempts failed here too.

So min and max at the same time.

Comment: @ConnorMacLeod Could you just try `min: 0`, this might work!

Comment: yes, how exactly at the same time?
Can you add it to your example?

$vAxis:{format:'# W',minValue:0,maxValue:300, viewWindow: {max: 300}},

Comment: gread! thank you very mutch! greetings from germany!